# iOS 8 Keyboard Dismissed delay after modal view controller is dismissed

Tags: ios8, modalviewcontroller

In iOS 8+ I noticed that if you have an textfield that is currently the `firstResponder` in a view controller that was presented, when the view controller is dismissed, the keyboard hangs around for around 1 second before being dismissed.

This occurs for both iOS 8.0 and 8.1 and **not** 7.1.

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to this, in iOS 8 it seems the **view doesn’t resign first responder status until it’s actually offscreen**.

http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2014/Sep/msg00391.html

Our workaround is to call `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in `-viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: When I try this, the keyboard starts to dismiss, but then jumps back up right before the view controller dismisses for some reason...

Comment: Still happening in iOS 9 - view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3/4**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Also if it's not resigning try calling `resignFirstResponder` on the text field you're trying to end typing on.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.viewWillDisappear(animated)`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Yes! Great comment. If Ricks adds this to his answer it will get an upvote from me.