# Keyboard from UIAlertController dismisses with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I'm trying to make a login dialog in `UIAlertController`.
Here is my code:

```
+ (void)authorizationDialogShow
{
    __block UITextField *loginTextField;
    __block UITextField *passwordTextField;

UIAlertController *authorizationAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Authorization"
                                                                            message:@"Enter login and password."
                                                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[authorizationAlert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
    loginTextField = textField;
    loginTextField.placeholder = @"Login";
}];

[authorizationAlert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
    passwordTextField = textField;
    passwordTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
    passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
}];

[authorizationAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                         NSString *login = loginTextField.text;
                                                         NSString *password = passwordTextField.text;
                                                         [GitAuthorization startAuthorizationWithLogin:login password:password];
                                                     }]];

[authorizationAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                         NSLog(@"End editing");
                                                         [authorizationAlert.view endEditing:YES];
                                                         [loginTextField resignFirstResponder];
                                                         [passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
                                                     }]];

[authorizationAlert show];
}
```

The problem is in cancel UIAlertAction. When I pressed this action, the keyboard dismissed with some delay. Not at the same time as `UIAlertController`. What's the problem?

I'm using pod `FFGlobalAlertController`. [Here some example of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5i5O.gif).

Comment: => try to dismiss keyboard on main thread or main queue

Comment: I've tried to execute handler of cancel action in main queue (dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                 ...                });). But I still have the same problem =(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue using `UIAlertController`.
My solution is to add a category on `UIAlertController` and call `[self.view endEditing:YES]` on `viewWillDisappear`. Import the category in **prefix.pch** if it's used widely.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Thank for the answer from micap. See link below for detail: 
[iOS 8 Keyboard Dismissed delay after modal view controller is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306381/ios-8-keyboard-dismissed-delay-after-modal-view-controller-is-dismissed)